# Why is time.Now() and time.Unix() different?

Tags: go

Recently I was given the below code snippet in an interview:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t1 := time.Now()
    t2 := time.Unix(0, int64(time.Now().Nanosecond()))
    fmt.Println(t1.Nanosecond())
    fmt.Println(t2.Nanosecond())
    fmt.Println(t1 == t2)
}
```

If you see the values printed by Nanosecond() function is equal , however the time objects are not. Can someone please explain why is this so?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#hdr-Monotonic_Clocks

Comment: TL;DR: `time.Now` returns a time including a monotonic clock reading, `time.Unix` does not.

Comment: And you are passing in `0` to time.Unix, so it's 0 seconds (+ some number of nanoseconds) after the epoch?

Comment: In addition to all the other comments, you cannot compare time values with `==` anyway. Use [Time.Equal](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Equal) instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Nanosecond):

> Nanosecond returns the nanosecond offset **within the second** specified by t, in the range [0, 999999999].

In other words, the `Time.Nanosecond()` method gives a number of how many nanoseconds since the last second.

So given that, this code:

```golang
time.Unix(0, int64(time.Now().Nanosecond()))
```

Can only produce a time that is less than 1 second after the Unix epoch.